# Why are my arrays getting sorted?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, methods, scope

*Hello and thanks all*

**INFO:**

This program is for a class assignment

The assignment is to use an array to simulate a lottery

I use 1D arrays of ints to represent the numbers on a lottery ticket

The methods I used were specified, so I can't move any fxn from one method to another (ex: I couldn't determine if the user won the lottery in the main method instead of in the designated method)

**THE PROBLEM:**

what i get - the display method shows my user-entered array sorted from least to greatest

what i want - the original array entered by the user

my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
public class Program2 {
  /*notes
  the numbers do not have to match in order
  you must validate all user input
  numeric output should be displayed with commas
  the code should be written using efficient processing
  use comments, naming conventions, and program structure
  */
  //main method
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner kbr = new Scanner(System.in); //scanner object for user input
    boolean auto = false;
    int choice;
    int[] yourTix;
    int[] winningTix;
    int tries = 0;
    int[] freq = new int[20];

    //display lottery info
    System.out.println("Welcome to the Wacky Lottery Program!");
    System.out.println("1 - Pick my own");
    System.out.println("2 - Computer picks for me");

    //validation loop
    do {
      choice = kbr.nextInt();

      if (choice < 1 || choice > 2)
        System.out.println("Invalid input. please enter either 1 or 2");

    } while (choice < 1 || choice > 2);

    //selecting automatic choice or not
    if (choice == 2)
      auto = false;
    else
      auto = true;

    //generating your ticket
    yourTix = yourTix(auto);

    //this do/while loop keeps generating winning tickets until you win
    do {
      //get new winning ticket
      winningTix = winningTix();

      //check frequency of each number and add to the frequency accumulator array
      for (int i = 0; i < winningTix.length; i++) {
        //accumulate frequency @ index that is equal to winningTix[i]
        int num = winningTix[i] - 1;
        freq[num]++;
      }

      //accumulating the number of tries
      tries++;
    } while (win(yourTix, winningTix) == false);

    //using the display method to print out the stats of this lottery
    display(yourTix, winningTix, tries, freq);


  }

  //method that determines the user's ticket numbers
  public static int[] yourTix(boolean auto) {
    Random r = new Random();
    Scanner kbr = new Scanner(System.in); //scanner object for user input
    int[] tix = new int[5]; //creating a new array of integers with 5 integers

    //this loop gets the user's input for each number on the ticket
    for (int i = 0; i < tix.length; i++) {
      if (auto == true) {
        System.out.print("Please enter number " + (i + 1) + ": ");
        do {
          tix[i] = kbr.nextInt();
          if (tix[i] < 1 || tix[i] > 20)
            System.out.println("Invalid input. Please only enter 1-20");
        } while (tix[i] < 1 || tix[i] > 20);
      } else {
        tix[i] = r.nextInt(19) + 1;
      }
    }

    //return the ticket array
    return tix;

  }

  //method to determine the winning numbers
  public static int[] winningTix() {
    Random r = new Random();
    int[] winningTix = new int[5];

    for (int i = 0; i < winningTix.length; i++)
      winningTix[i] = r.nextInt(20) + 1;

    return winningTix;
  }

  //method to determine if the user won
  public static boolean win(int[] yt, int[] wt) {
    boolean same = true;
    int startScan, index, minIndex, minValue;


    //sort user's array numerical order
    for (startScan = 0; startScan < (yt.length - 1); startScan++) {
      minIndex = startScan;
      minValue = yt[startScan];
      for (index = startScan + 1; index < yt.length; index++) {
        if (yt[index] < minValue) {
          minValue = yt[index];
          minIndex = index;
        }
      }
      yt[minIndex] = yt[startScan];
      yt[startScan] = minValue;
    }
    //sort computer's array numerical order
    for (startScan = 0; startScan < (wt.length - 1); startScan++) {
      minIndex = startScan;
      minValue = wt[startScan];
      for (index = startScan + 1; index < wt.length; index++) {
        if (wt[index] < minValue) {
          minValue = wt[index];
          minIndex = index;
        }
      }
      wt[minIndex] = wt[startScan];
      wt[startScan] = minValue;
    }


    index = 0; // Loop control variable

    // determine whether the elements contain the same data
    while (same && index < wt.length) {
      if (yt[index] != wt[index])
        same = false;
      index++;
    }

    //return whether or not the winning array and the user's array matches
    return same;
  }



  //method that displays and writes to file
  public static void display(int[] winning, int[] user, int tries, int[] freq) {
    //message indicating the win
    System.out.println("You won!");
    System.out.println();

    //display winning lottery ticket numbers in their original order
    System.out.println("Here is the winning ticket");
    for (int i = 0; i < winning.length; i++)
      System.out.println(winning[i]);
    System.out.println();

    //display user numbers in the original order
    System.out.println("Here is your ticket");
    for (int i = 0; i < user.length; i++)
      System.out.println(user[i]);
    System.out.println();

    //the number of times it took to get a match with a winning ticket
    System.out.printf("It took %,d tries to win", tries);
    System.out.println();

    //the number of times each value 1-20 was generated for a winning lottery ticket
    for (int i = 0; i < freq.length; i++) {
      System.out.printf("The number %d was generated %,d times", i + 1, freq[i]);
      System.out.println();
    }

    //this should also be written to a file

    //this should also be written to a file
    //note: if tie, display all the numbers

  }
}
```

Comment: Yes. Ghosts. Hire Pac Man.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [Please provide a minimal, complete, and verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

In your method:

public static boolean win(int[] yt, int[] wt) {

You are doing sorting on the array:

```
//sort user's array numerical order
    for (startScan = 0; startScan < (yt.length - 1); startScan++) {
      minIndex = startScan;
      minValue = yt[startScan];
      for (index = startScan + 1; index < yt.length; index++) {
        if (yt[index] < minValue) {
          minValue = yt[index];
          minIndex = index;
        }
      }
      yt[minIndex] = yt[startScan];
      yt[startScan] = minValue;
    }
    //sort computer's array numerical order
    for (startScan = 0; startScan < (wt.length - 1); startScan++) {
      minIndex = startScan;
      minValue = wt[startScan];
      for (index = startScan + 1; index < wt.length; index++) {
        if (wt[index] < minValue) {
          minValue = wt[index];
          minIndex = index;
        }
      }
```

That's why it would be sorting the array.

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You are sorting the array in the `win` method.  If you don't want to sort the original array, and you are only doing this for comparison purposes, try sorting a copy instead.

You can add these lines so that you only operate on a copy.

```
public static boolean win(int[] yt, int[] wt) {
    yt = yt.clone(); // take a copy first
    wt = wt.clone(); // take a copy first
```

Using code you have already used, you could write

```
public static int[] copy(int[] array) {
    int[] copy = new int[array.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        copy[i] = array[i];
    return copy;
}

public static boolean win(int[] yt, int[] wt) {
    yt = copy(yt); // take a copy first
    wt = copy(wt); // take a copy first
```

Comment: thanks this fixed it! but one problem, im not allowed to use any methods not learned in my class, or I get docked points

Comment: is there some other way i can fix this method similarly?

Comment: will it work if i just say oldarray = newarray? (except use a loop to copy each integer in the array)

Comment: @Nora `newarray` and `oldarray` are references to an array.  When you assign one to another, you make them reference the same array.  This doesn't create copy the array so if you change the array through one reference it appears to change in every other reference to the same array.

Comment: @Nora I have added code which doesn't use a method you haven't used already.